# CSS is not showing in the admin page -Django

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

**So I upload my site to digitalocean and when I went to the admin page the CSS was not showing**

I visit all these sites but nothing seems to work

[Django doc-static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)

[Pythonanywhere-DjangoStaticFiles](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles)

[StackOverflow -why my django admin site does not have the css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420378/why-my-django-admin-site-does-not-have-the-css-style)

I set up my STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL, and then I ran

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

And here is my seting

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  '/home/django/django_project/django_project/static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), 
]
```

Comment: How have you deployed it? Have you made sure your nginx/apache is configured to serve your static files?

Comment: You were right there was a problem in my configuration file, Thanks @JonClements

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying an Absolute Path for your join.

`os.path.join(BASE_DIR, arg2)` means join the current directory that is being executed and append the second argument.

Comment: so should I write it like this

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT ='/home/django/django_project/django_project/static'`

Answer (score 0):

add these lines into your settings.py file

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (                                                            
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),                                          
 )
```

Comment: I did but nothing has changed. when I run it on the local server it works fine but when I go to production it doesn't show up

Comment: How do you serve the Django app in production? Without more information about your configuration (nginx confs, gunicorn, etc) we won't be able to help you.

Comment: is nginx serve your static files you should add these line in nginx.conf
 location /static/ {
        alias   /home/<your_path_to_static_root>/;
    }